# Why might a join on a subquery be slow? What could be done to make it faster? (SQL)

Tags: sql

This is a data science interview question.

My understanding of subqueries is that especially with correlated subqueries where the is dependent on the outer query, the correlated subquery requires more or one values to be passed to it by the outer query before the subquery can be resolved. This means that you need to process the subquery more times, one for each row in the outer query.

In particular, in this case, if the inner and outer query returns M and N rows, respectively, the total run time could be O(M*N)

So in general, that would be my answer for why running a subquery could be slow, but am I missing anything else that pertains to joining on a subquery? Also I'm not really sure what could be done to make it faster.

I would of course appreciate any tips or help.

Thanks!

Comment: Always look at the execution plan...

Answer (score 3):

I think that your answer should be correct: subqueries are slow, if they are correlated. Uncorrelated subquery are only evaluated a single time.

What can be done to speedup: correlated subqueries can be rewritten as joins! And join queries can be executed must faster!

If you use a good RDBMS, the optimizer is often able to rewrite a correlated subquery into a join query (however, not for all cases). However, if you use simple RDBMS, there is either no optimizer at all or the optimizer is not very advance (ie, cannot unnest subqueries into join queries). For those cases, you need to rewrite you query by hand.

Comment: Fair enough. I removed my "side remark" in my answer. (Don't want to blame any system...)

Answer (score 1):

Wow - what an open ended question! I'm not sure how far outside the box they want you to think, but some possible reasons:

**Criteria too broad**

The criteria for your query may be too broad, there may be extra clauses you could add that would reduce the sheer amount of data the RDBMS has to process.

**Lack of indexes**

If there aren't any indexes on the pertinent columns, the RDBMS may have to resort to full table scans which could be slow.

**Stale stats**

If statistics haven't been updated for a while, the RDBMS may not have the full picture of the skew of the data which can affect the execution time massively.

**Physical arrangement of database**

If the indexes and tables are on the same physical drive(s), this can create IO contention.

**Parallelism**

The RDBMS may not be set up correctly for parallelism meaning that the RDBMS may not be making the best use of the available hardware.

**Scheduling**

The time when the query is run can affect the execution time. Would the query be better run out of hours?

**Data changes**

Data changes can affect the skew of the data and in rare cases create cartesians. On large databases there should be full traceability of data at row level at least to track down data issues.

**Locking**

Related to high levels of use is the issue of locking. If you require clean reads, there may be contention on the required data which could slow down the query.

**Misleading execution plans**

You may have pulled the execution plans but these don't always tell the full story. Cost is a function of CPU and IO but your system may be more bound on one than the other. Some RDBMSs have setting that can force the optimiser to skew the cost towards one side or the other to produce better plans.

**Static data not being cached**

If you have some static data you're recalculating each time, this will affect the cost. Such data should be stored in an indexed or temporary table to reduce the amount of processing that the RDBMs needs to process.

**Query simply too complex**

Whilst the query may scan perfectly well to you, if you can break it up into chunks using temporary tables or the like, this could perform significantly better.

---

I'm going to stop there as I could easily spend the rest of the day adding to this, but hopefully this gives you a flavour.

Comment: Your answer aims for "Why is a query slow", but the question was about subqueries.

Comment: The corollary of your assertion is that none of these, if addressed could improve the performance of a correlated sub-query. With respect, I disagree.